# Showing a hidden div that is added dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are a lot of questions similar to the one I'm about to ask, but none of them seem to help me. I have a div that uses the twitter bootstrap class `hide` so that it is hidden. The div is loaded with some other content that is loaded dynamically via ajax. I am using jquery and the delegate function to be able to unhide that div when a checkbox is checked. I've verified that the click function is being called and that the appropriate if statement is true but the div is not being shown. Below is the code for my html (I'm using asp.net mvc and razor):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Checkboxes)
 {
     <label class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes" value=@item>
                    @item
      </label>
  }
  <div class="display-field hide">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Other, new { @cols = 100, @rows = 5 })
  </div>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
 $('body').delegate('#Checkboxes', 'click', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "other")
        $("#Other").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `show` changes the `style.display`.
Bootstrap on the other hand uses a CSS class 'hide'.

These two are not compatible.

A solution:

```
$('body').delegate('#Checkboxes', 'click', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "other")
        $("#Other").removeClass("hide");
});
```

**Update:**
Something fishy still :)
Try changing the code to:

```
$('body').delegate('#Checkboxes', 'click', function () {
    console.log("click event fired!");
    console.log("this.val() is " + $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == "other")
        console.log("entered the if");
        console.log("other exists? " + $("#Other").length);
        $("#Other").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Depending what gets (not) printed to the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome) you should be able to further narrow down the problem.

If that is still not working, I would advise to create a minimal case in a JSFiddle, it might yield you more response.

Comment: It wasn't working because #Other referred to the textarea. The textarea never had the hide class, it's parent div did.